# How to use linq functions like Sum() with dynamic variable

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

```
Type t = Type.GetType(obj.ToString());                 
PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty("Test");
dynamic kk =  p.GetValue(obj, null);
```

In this, Test is an int List. I need to get the sum of all the values from int list ie., kk.

Comment: Why not cast it to a `IEnumreable<int>` than?

Comment: Beaware of Microsoft, Sueing Linq is not a good idea IMO.

Answer (score 6):

```
var list = p.GetValue(obj, null) as IEnumerable<int>;

var result = list.Sum();
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer, but why using `var` on known types? `list` is always `IEnumerable<int>` and result is always `int`, I don't see the need to use `var` rather than just strong type them.

Comment: Any time you use `var` you could also use the equivilent type. When you use var all the compiler does **at compile time** is work out what the type is. A `var` variable **is still strongly typed**. I tend to use it when the type is obvious, or when it'd save a lot of typing.

Comment: @Bazz: Please read this article by Eric Lippert: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/20/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing.aspx. There is no way I can say it more clearly than he does.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Type t = Type.GetType(obj.ToString());
Type t = obj.GetType(); // You might be able to replace the above line with this, simpler verison.
PropertyInfo p = t.GetProperty("Test");
object kk =  p.GetValue(obj, null);
int Sum = (kk as List<int>).Sum();
```